Error when updating to CiviCRM 5.80.1
When trying to update to 5.80.1  in backdrop the upgrade screen hangs on "Finish Core Update on 5.80.1" even when leaving overnight.
If I reload the update screen i then get the error"
Error
Failed opening required 'activityical.civix.php' (include_path='.:File_Path/public_html/modules/civicrm/:File_Path/public_html/modules/civicrm//packages:.:File_Path/public_html/modules/civicrm:File_Path/public_html/modules/civicrm/packages:File_Path/public_html/modules/civicrm/vendor/tecnickcom:File_Path/public_html/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/auth_sasl:File_Path/public_html/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear_exception:File_Path/public_html/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/console_getopt:File_Path/public_html/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src:File_Path/public_html/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/db:File_Path/public_html/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/log:File_Path/public_html/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/mail:File_Path/public_html/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/mail_mime:File_Path/public_html/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/net_socket:File_Path/public_html/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/net_smtp:File_Path/public_html/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/validate_finance_creditcard:.:/opt/alt/php83/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php83/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php')"
I am updating using the instructions on the Civicrm Systems Administration manual, so I dont now whats happening

What were the last entries from the log relating to the upgrade?
